# Ng-Select Selected are not updating from ngModel

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

I'm experiencing a problem that has me stumped. I have an ng-select. When loading records to the ngModel, it doesn't change the ng-select. The weirdest part is that on another page, the same code works.

I've tried numerous different options, even creating new arrays just to test. Also tried setTimeout to see if something is clearing the selection.

The HTML code

```
  <label>
    Add a Secondary channel
  </label>
  <br />
  <ng-select placeholder="Select schools" items="schoolsArray" [(ngModel)]="selectedSecondSchools" [multiple]="true" name="secondSchools"
  #secondSchools="ngModel">
  </ng-select>
</div>
```

The one function in the component. The array is declared as selectedSecondSchools[] = [];

```
getVodEventGameSecondaryChannels(vodEventId: number, vodEventGameId: number): string[] {
    let schoolIds: string[] = [];

    this.vodEventService
      .getVodEventGameSecondaryChannelsByGameId(vodEventId, vodEventGameId)
      .subscribe((sc: IVodEventGameSecondaryChannels[]) => {
        sc.forEach(gsc => {
          schoolIds.push(
            gsc.schoolId.toString());
        });
      });

    this.eventGame.gameSecondaryChannelIds = schoolIds;
    this.selectedSecondSchools = schoolIds;

    return schoolIds;
  }
```

When the data is returned, the returned IDs need to be selected within the ng-select and displayed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of `schoolsArray`. In your case, I guess, `schoolsArray` is a list of objects, while `ngModel` is an array of strings. ng-select doesn't know how to map strings from `ngModel` to objects from `items`.

Please see documentation for property `bindValue` to inform ng-select how to bind `items` keys to the model. https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select

To summarize, add `bindValue="id-property-name-in-items"` to ng-select tag.